# Comparing 2 objects and making alterations based on Match

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I have 2 objects with key-value pairs that should always be identical (match) otherwise I want to modify the value of the key in object #1 to "Some Value - Not available"

Here are my 2 objects:

Object #1

```
[
  {
    "name": "John",
    "age": "12",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "tina",
    "age": "19",
    "id": 2
  }]
```

Object #2 ( name checker)

```
 [
      {
        "value": "tina"
      },
      {
        "value": "Trevor"
      },
      {
        "value": "Donald"
      },
      {
        "value": "Elon"
      },
      {
        "value": "Pamela"
      },
      {
        "value": "Chris"
      },
      {
        "value": "Jackson"
      }
    ]
```

I would like to find out if **name** in Object #1 is found in Object #2 and if it is not found, add " - not available"

e.i

```
[
      {
        "name": "John - not available",
        "age": "12",
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "tina",
        "age": "19",
        "id": 2
      }
]
```

Important Note: **I'm using ES5** --- not ES6

Comment: There seems to be no [JSON objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) in the code ..?

Comment: `Array1.forEach(element => { if(!Array2.some(element2 => element2.value === element.name)){ element.name += " - not available"; } })`

Comment: @Teemu I wanted to minimize the question and make it easier to read

Comment: @MikeS. thanks! i'm giving that a go

Comment: "JS objects" would have been shorter, and correct ...

Comment: @Teemu [nor could there be](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). [Further information for OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: @Teemu "*"JS objects" would have been shorter, and correct ...*" even shorter: "objects". Still correct. We agree that "JSON objects" is both longer and incorrect.

Comment: @VLAZ But but, I've just linked to the documentation of  JSON object, it really exists, but is an intrinsic object in some JS enviroments.

Comment: @Teemu semantics, I guess. "JSON object" =  1. object *named* JSON 2. Object that *is* JSON. I was talking about the latter.

Comment: @MikeS. thanks for your solution - however I'm not using ES6 .. I'm using ES5

Comment: @VLAZ I have now added ES5 in the question -  for clarification

Comment: @fosowe Just translate the arrow functions in Mike's comment to function expressions then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work in **ES5**

```
object1.forEach(function(person) {
  var found = false;
  Object.keys(object2).forEach(function(key) {
    if (person.name === object2[key].value) {
      found = true;
    }
  });
  if (!found) {
    person.name = person.name + " - not available";
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't think `Object.values()` is in ES5. EDIT: Yep, checked and it's added in [ES8](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html)

Comment: @PeterSH thanks! note: I'm getting: object1.forEach is not a function... error

Comment: @fosowe Check the variable names of your objects, I named them object1 and object2, yours might be different.

Comment: @PeterSH Got it to work.. I had to  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject)) object1 and object2